# How to split English letters, numbers and Chinese characters in R?

Tags: r, office365

I need to split the strings of mixture of Chinese/English/numbers (e.g., "123-321-中文.jpg" or "001-123你好.png") or extract the Chinese words in the strings using R. Any solution for that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To extract the chinese words only,
We could use `str_extract`: extracting all non latin characters with `"[:alpha:]+"`:

```
library(stringr)

string <- c("123-321-中文.jpg", "001-123你好.png")

str_extract(string, "[:alpha:]+")
```

output:

```
[1] "中文" "你好"
```

Comment: Thanks. That is what I want. If I want to extract other parts excluding the chinese words (e.g., "123-321-" or "001-123"), what should I do?

Comment: We could use `tools::file_path_sans_ext(stringr::str_remove_all(string, pattern))` will give `[1] "123-321-" "001-123"`. Learned here: <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71243061/in-str-remove-combine-a-pattern-with-a-regex-in-one-line/71243126#71243126>