# In str_remove: Combine a pattern with a regex in one line

Tags: r, vector, stringr

**I have this vector:**

```
vec <- c("abc-xyz.png", "abc-xyz-12.jpg")

[1] "abc-xyz.png"    "abc-xyz-12.jpg"
```

**and this not changeable predefined pattern**

```
pattern <- c("abc|xyz")
```

**I would like to combine this two procedures**

```
library(stringr)

str_remove_all(vec, pattern)
[1] "-.png"    "--12.jpg"

str_remove_all(vec, '\\..*')
[1] "abc-xyz"    "abc-xyz-12"
```

**in one line like:**

```
str_remove_all(vec, pattern & '\\..*') # does not work
```

Expected output:

```
[1] "-"    "--12"
```

**My question: is it possible to combine a pattern and a regex in the pattern argument of `str_replace`**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a `|` pattern with `sprintf` or `paste`

```
stringr::str_remove_all(vec, sprintf("%s|\\..*", pattern))
[1] "-"    "--12"
```

---

Or another option is `file_path_sans_ext` on the output from `str_remove`

```
tools::file_path_sans_ext(stringr::str_remove_all(vec, pattern))
[1] "-"    "--12"
```

Comment: I tried `paste` earlier but instead of `|` with a `,`. Once again master Thank you.